# USB Control of a Sony Action Camera

Tags: camera, usb, controls, sony

I am trying to find an action camera that I can control over USB and then download the video over USB, all programmatically. I would like to use one of the Sony ones, preferably the HDR-AS50. However I want to know whether controlling it over USB is doable before I go out and buy it. I know that it isn't officially supported by Sony's Remote Camera Control API/SDK however I also know that it is technically possible. I would prefer to use Python, however I am willing to use whatever language I need in order to achieve this.

Anyone know the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no supported way to control the camera over USB. You can have a look at this thread to see related questions on this topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsony-camera-api%5D+usb